# How to use Dead letter in RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I've setup RabbitMQ and have followed the tutorials and I've got a basic pub/sub setup going on. I've now got to to the resilience part and handling bad actors. Eg, messages that can never be actioned. Rather than deleting them completely I'm wanting them to be redirected to a dead letter queue so I can inspect them later.

With MSMQ its a simple process of adding .error on the queue namespace but Rabbit seems to be more indepth and low level.

I've got the following configured for my consumer
constructor code

```
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AsyncUpdateProcessor>();

        InboundQueueName = options.Value.InboundQueueName;

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = options.Value.Hostname,
            UserName = options.Value.Username,
            Password = options.Value.Password
        };

        // create connection  
        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();

        // create channel  
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        _channel.ExchangeDeclare("some.exchange.name", "direct");

        Dictionary<String, Object> args = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        args.Add("x-dead-letter-exchange", "some.exchange.name");
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: InboundQueueName,
            durable: false,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false,
            args);

    }
```

But the declare queue errors

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: 'The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'msg.inbound' in vhost '/': received the value 'some.exchange.name' of type 'longstr' but current is none', classId=50, methodId=10'

Answer (score 0):

Message is clear, you have some other queue `msg.inbound`, which is created before the current queue `InboundQueueName`, so you you to either delete the  `msg.inbound` or recrate it with the `x-dead-letter-exchange`

Comment: So based on that if I used the management console and deleted the queue it would work?

Comment: yes, but if these queues have data then you to manually move the data to some other queue and then delete it.

Comment: Brilliant. That queue has a special flag against it but the messages that failed. Eg got nack didn’t appear anywhere. I expected it to be somewhere.

Comment: Sadly not. I’ve deleted the options from the queue creation and added a policy in the management console which applies to all queues using a wildcard regex. Even then it’s not showing the message anywhere.

Comment: It will apply on all the queues under the same policy.